# Setup Launch4j to create exe file include photos

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage, launch4j

I'm using Launch4j to create a exe file for my code. The exe file created successfully but because I use in my code some images into GUI, the exe file doesn't work. How can I insert my images into the exe file? Thanx

Comment: Have you tried running the JAR file before making an EXE?
Are you sure the images are to blame here?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run jar file before and the problem is same.

Comment: @Ibrahim then it has **nothing to do with Launch4J**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My projects usually have a folder structure like this:

```
/src
    /main
         /java
         /resources
/test
    ...
```

(because I use Maven; Launch4J has a good Maven plugin, btw.).

I put all images, that need to be available for the application, into the `/resources` folder.
During the build process, images are copied into the output folder, where all the compiled `.class` files are. The images are now in the classpath.

To access resources (i.e. images) in your classpath, you can use the classloader, such as:

- Resources in the root directory (`src/main/resources/image.jpg`) can be accessed through the System ClassLoader:

  ```
  ClassLoader.getSystemResource("image.jpg");
  ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
  ```
- Resources in other packages (e.g. for `com.example.MyClass` the resource should be at `src/main/resources/com/example/image.jpg`) can be accessed through the class itself:

  ```
  MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("image.jpg");
  ```

Launch4J never complains about that and uses the images without any problem, even in .exe files.

Comment: That work perfect. One more question, if you need to run your app in another computer, what path file you put for you images into your code?

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain a bit how to used it.